# Anomaly when using "with" with find/replace and setting MatchWholeWord boolean

Tags: vba, ms-word

I thought I would share the following as it is either a vba feature or I am doing something wrong.

I want to find Whole Words, so I set the select flag `Selection.Find.MatchWholeWord = True`

The following code does not retain the setting of the MatchWholeWord to True.  Well it does, but then removes the setting in the second "with" block

```
With Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Forward = True
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = True       <-------------
    .MatchWildcards = False  
    .MatchWholeWord = True  <=============
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.Text = "^&"
    .Replacement.Highlight = True
End With

For Each wrdRef In docRef.Words
    If Asc(Left(wrdRef, 1)) > 32 Then
        With Selection.Find
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Text = wrdRef
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        End With
    End If
Next wrdRef
```

However, when I move the MatchWholeWord statement to the second "with" block it works.

```
With Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Forward = True
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = True      <------------
    .MatchWildcards = False         
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.Text = "^&"
    .Replacement.Highlight = True
End With

For Each wrdRef In docRef.Words
    If Asc(Left(wrdRef, 1)) > 32 Then
        With Selection.Find
            .MatchWholeWord = True <=========
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Text = wrdRef
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        End With
    End If
Next wrdRef
```

Now, that might be ok, but the flag setting statement `MatchCase = True` remains set.

Question: Why would the Selection.Find.MatchWholeWord and Selection.Find.MatchCase behave differently in conjunction with the "With" statement?

(Reference:  I copied this code from:
http://word.tips.net/T000502_Highlight_Words_from_a_Word_List.html

Note, the other change I had to make to this code was add the line `.Replacement.Highlight = True`

Comment: Did not reproduce for me.

Comment: Spooky:  upgraded from 2013 to 2016, orginal code now works